# How to check if a library is present during installation?

Tags: installation, theming

How can I check if the library, which is required by my module, is present while the module is getting installed?

I have used `hook_requirements` with the `libraries_detect` function with `REQUIREMENT_ERROR` severity. This restricts the module from getting installed irrespective of the library is present of not.

Here is my code:

```
function hook_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = array();
  $t = get_t();
  if ($phase == 'install') {
    if (function_exists("libraries_detect") && !libraries_detect('external-lib-api')) {
      $requirements['library_api'] = array(
        'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR,
        'description' => $t(
          'The required Libarary is not installed.'
        )
      );
    }
  }

  return $requirements;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in this? Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is one of the working example from my module. I hope this helps you

```
function sfs_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = array();
  $t = get_t();
  if ($phase == 'install' && function_exists('libraries_get_path')) {
     $plupload_path = libraries_get_path('plupload');
     $chosen_path = libraries_get_path('chosen');
     if (!$plupload_path) {
       $requirements['plupload'] = array(
         'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR,
         'description' => $t('Secure File Share module requires !plupload, which is missing. Download and extract the entire contents of the archive into the %path directory on your server.',  array('!plupload' => l($t('Plupload Library'), 'https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/archive/v1.5.8.zip'), '%path' => 'sites/all/libraries/plupload')), 
       );
     }
     if (!$chosen_path) {
        $requirements['chosen_js'] = array(
          'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR,
          'description' => $t('Secure File Share module requires !chosen, which is missing. Download and extract the entire contents of the archive into the %path directory on your server.', array('!chosen' => l($t('Chosen Library'), 'https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/download/v1.3.0/chosen_v1.3.0.zip'), '%path' => 'sites/all/libraries/chosen')),
        );
      }
  }
  return $requirements;
}
```

---

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
hook_requirements($phase)
```

into this

```
 Name_of_your_module_requirements($phase)
```

"library_api" is not a Library is a module https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries

for create a module dependency you can add a line into your module .info file like this :

```
dependencies[] = libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at how module [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) is handling this, around [line 429 
of forena.module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/forena/tree/forena.module#n429):

```
function forena_library_file($library) {
  $libraries = array(
      'dataTables' => 'dataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
      'mpdf' => 'mpdf/mpdf.php',
      'SVGGraph' => 'SVGGraph/SVGGraph.php',
      'prince' => 'prince/prince.php'
  );
  $path = isset($libraries[$library]) && file_exists('sites/all/libraries/' . $libraries[$library]) ? 'sites/all/libraries/' . $libraries[$library] : '';
  return $path;
}
```

FYI: Forena interfaces with up to 4 libraries, which is why you'll 4 such entries around there.